# swipes are not getting detected

Tags: android, touch, swipe, gesture, gesture-recognition

In the below posted code, I am trying to detect swipes using `onDown` and `onFling` but when I run the App, nothing appears.

I expected to see output coming from `onFling` when I hold touching the screen and drag my finger across it quickly, but i received nothing. Also, I expected to see the output coming from `onDown` when I press on the screen, but as well, nothing showed up.

please let me know what I am missing Or I misundersatnd the functionalities of `onFling` on `onDown`?!

JavaCode:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.swipe_gesture_activivty);

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new MySwipeGestureDetector());

            mViewGestureDetector = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };
    final TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accXLabel);      
}

private class MySwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener implements OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You're not adding the OnGestureListener to any view, as far the posted code shows (?)

Comment: will be edited shortly...posted wrong code

Comment: @Amr you have to register/link the view(s)"buttons, framelayout, relatives layouts,...etc) you are willing to detect a swipe across them, with an object of Gesturedetector class. I think you are missing this step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume for an example that, all your views in the layout.xml file are wrapped inside a `framelayout` and you want your swipes to be detectable across the entire `framelayout`. If so, register your `framelayout` to the object of the type `GestureDetector` as shown in the following code:

```
FrameLayout mFL = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayoutID);

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new MySwipeGestureDetector());
    mFL.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Regarding the `simpleOnGestureListener`, here is how to implement `onFling`. it works for me.:

```
//define these variables globally:
/* private static final int MIN_DIST = 100;
private static final int MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
private static final int THRESHOLD_VELOC = 200;*/
...
...
...
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.i("SwipeGesture", "Left Swipe");
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.i("SwipeGesture", "Right Swipe");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `GestureDetector` works by translating multiple MotionEvents into particular gestures. To do so, it must receive the input from a view's touch events.

You're simply missing

```
view.setOnTouchListener(mViewGestureDetector);
```

for a particular view (the one you want to catch flings on).